# cvQueryFrame from thread

Tags: multithreading, opencv

I'm trying to receive frame using opencv(3.1.0) from webcam on windows inside separate thread. See example below. It stucks on cvQueryFrame(TestThread) and can't return anything. no errors... Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>

void TestThread(void *param);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    CvCapture* capture;
    HANDLE handle;  
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if (!capture) {     
        std::cout << "capture error";
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    std::cout << "main: " << frame->width;

    handle = (HANDLE) _beginthread( TestThread, 0, capture);
    WaitForSingleObject(handle,INFINITE);

    std::cout << "done";
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}

void TestThread(void *param)
{           
    CvCapture* capture=(CvCapture*)param;
    IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
    std::cout << "thread: " << frame->width;
    _endthread();
}
```

Comment: What if you move the `capture` initialization into the thread as well? It might not like having the object created in one thread and used in another.

Comment: Yes, if I init CvCapture inside thread then it can query frame. Thanks )